# Eclipse OutOfMemory

Tags: eclipse

My physical memory is 8GB and my Eclipse VM configuration is 
-ea -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M.

I still got a "

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

" problem.

How can i fix this? Thank you

Comment: It sounds like it could be a VM issue, or you could be experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=92250). When does the error occur?

Comment: In eclipse when I try to launch an application.

Answer (score 1):

That `-Xmx1024m` means "Never use more than one gigabyte for the heap." If you'd like to double the heap size that Eclipse can use, change it to `-Xmx2048m`.

Comment: i increased to 2048, then i got the message "Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Comment: That means that despite the 8GB RAM (which suggested a 64-bit machine) you're running a 32-bit JVM. You're limited to about -Xmx1500m, then. Still, will be an improvement. If you are running a 64-bit OS, download a 64-bit Java implementation and/or a 64-bit Eclipse distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is - even though it is an OutOfMemoryError - not thrown because you don't have enough memory, and therefore increasing your memory won't solve the problem you have. For details, see [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: While the link may answer the question, please list the important points in the answer also. Doing so would make sure that your answer remains valid even if the link becomes inactive.